# Why not make up your own times to pray from non Muslim

Tags: halal-haram, salat, human-rights

When a non Muslim learns that Muslims are required to pray at particular times of the day, his reply was you should be able to decide for yourself when to pray. For example, Perhaps you are busy today or tired so you pray less and pray more on other days. Basically you choose how many times to pray per day and when. Why is this not a good idea from an Islamic perspective?

Comment: Because a muslim is a person who submits to Allah not the other way around?

Comment: Salam and welcome to Islam SE the Q&A site about Islam. To make yourself familiar with our site and model I strongly suggest you to take our [tour] and check our [help].

Comment: A muslim is someone who obeys the Allah. This is the reason. Muslims do not act arbitrarily.

Comment: @Mahdi I don't really like it when you referred to Allah as 'the Allah'. It doesn't seem right for some reason.

Answer (score 3):

The daily [prayer times](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salah_times) are "prescribed" in Islam, i.e., Muslims believe that they are required by Allah to perform their prayers at certain times.  The Qur'an doesn't directly tell us to pray at precisely these times, but the requirements have been passed down from Muhammad or deduced from Islamic literature by scholars (see e.g. [Islam Q&A](https://islamqa.info/en/1092)).

There's some flexibility:

- usually there's a window of an hour to a few hours (it varies with the location of the sun, however),
- it's permissible for a traveller to pray fewer prayers ([Qur'an 4:101](https://quran.com/4/101)),
- women with menses do not pray (see [Islam Q&A](https://islamqa.info/en/70438)),
- praying on a flight is more relaxed (see [Islam Q&A](https://islamqa.info/en/82536)),
- sometimes Muslims "merge" prayers (performing the same prayers, but in three batches rather than five), which is common when someone has a commitment, and (from my experience) is normal in Shia Islam (see [Al-Islam](https://www.al-islam.org/questions-jurisprudence-abdul-husayn-sharafuddin-al-musawi/chapter-one-combining-two-prayers)).

So Muslims have some ability to choose for themselves when to pray.  Nevertheless, it's generally best to pray (punctually) just after the appointed time.  Also, if you're really in a hurry, it's possible to pray quickly.  When you're prepared in advance and know what to do, it doesn't take all that long.